# How do I add values from a csv file to a list?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot

```
x,y
6.1101,17.592
5.5277,9.1302
8.5186,13.662
7.0032,11.854
5.8598,6.8233
8.3829,11.886
7.4764,4.3483
8.5781,12
6.4862,6.5987
5.0546,3.8166
5.7107,3.2522
14.164,15.505
```

How do I put each value for x in a list and the same for y values ?
I'm basically trying to create a plot.

Comment: What have you tried? And if you're not sure how to do this, I think i'd wait till you've got some more experience under your belt before trying ML...

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list)
with open("my.csv") as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
    for row in dr:
        for key, val in row.items():
            columns[key].append(float(val))

print(columns["x"])
print(columns["y"])
```

Gives:

```
[6.1101, 5.5277, 8.5186, 7.0032, 5.8598, 8.3829, 7.4764, 8.5781, 6.4862, 5.0546, 5.7107]
[17.592, 9.1302, 13.662, 11.854, 6.8233, 11.886, 4.3483, 12.0, 6.5987, 3.8166, 3.2522]
```

Obviously this is assuming that the contents will be numeric data that needs to be converted to `float` (as the question says that you are trying to create a plot). If there were non-numeric values, this would raise a `ValueError`, so if this might be the case then you would need to test for this or handle the exception.

Comment: @SuperStew Just because it handles the header row for you.

Comment: ahh, thats handy

Answer (score 0):

use `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', sep=',',header=None)
```

Comment: technically OP asked for a list

Comment: @SuperStew OP: `so I can use it for machine learning`

Comment: Just because op wants to use it for "machine learning" doesn't mean you should assume he wants to use pandas. OP asked to put his data in a list and you have given him a dataframe instead.

Comment: @JacekRojek yea but thats his problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas`, an example below.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

x = df.x.tolist()
y = df.y.tolist()
```

`x` and `y` variables will contain values from column `x` and `y` in your `CSV` as lists respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to use csv module functionnality.
First create a csv reader function:

```
import csv

def csv_dict_reader(file, has_header=False, skip_comment_char=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Reads CSV file into memory


    :param file: (str) path to csv file to read
    :param has_header: (bool) skip first line
    :param skip_comment_char: (str) optional character which, if found on first row, will skip row
    :param delimiter: (char) CSV delimiter char
    :param fieldnames: (list) CSV field names for dictionnary creation
    :param kwargs:
    :return: csv object that can be iterated
    """
    with open(file) as fp:
        csv_data = csv.DictReader(fp, **kwargs)
        # Skip header
        if has_header:
            next(csv_data)

        fieldnames = kwargs.get('fieldnames')
        for row in csv_data:
            # Skip commented out entries
            if fieldnames is not None:
                if skip_comment_char is not None:
                    if not row[fieldnames[0]].startswith(skip_comment_char):
                        yield row
                else:
                    yield row
            else:
                # list(row)[0] is key from row, works with Python 3.7+
                if skip_comment_char is not None:
                    if not row[list(row)[0]].startswith(skip_comment_char):
                        yield row
                else:
                yield row
```

The above function returns a generator that can be iterated over, which is useful if your csv file is very large, so it hasn't to fit in memory at once.
Then use that function to read your data and iterate over the values

```
fieldnames = ('x', 'y')
data = csv_dict_reader('/path/to/my/file')
x_list = []
y_list = []
for row in data:
    x_list.append(row['x'])
    y_list.append(row['y'])
```

Btw, perhaps using two separate lists isn't the most optimized way.
You could remove both lists and simply use `row['x']` directly.

Comment: list has no `add` method - did you mean `append`?

Comment: @alaniwi Thanks, that happens when you comment at 11pm ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pandas` to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('cord.csv', sep=',')

x = df['x'].tolist()
y = df['y'].tolist()
```

output:

```
[6.1101, 5.5277, 8.5186, 7.0032, 5.8598, 8.3829, 7.4764, 8.5781, 6.4862, 5.0546, 5.7107, 14.164]
[17.592, 9.1302, 13.662, 11.854, 6.8233, 11.886, 4.3483, 12.0, 6.5987, 3.8166, 3.2522, 15.505]
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = None)

print(type(df.columns))

print(type(df.index))

then once you know the default type of the data sets, you can use
df.columns.tolist()

df.index.tolist()

print(type(data.columns.tolist()))
print(type(data.index.tolist()))